# How to distinguish a trivial gauge transformation from a non-trivial one?

Tags: lagrangian-formalism, gauge-theory, variational-principle, gauge-invariance, variational-calculus

Two days ago I posted a [post](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/757423/363071) that discusses a very generic gauge transformation. I repeat it here. Suppose we have an action $S=S(a,b,c)$ which is a functional of the fields $a,\, b,\,$ and $c$. We denote the variation of $S$ wrt to a given field, say $a$, i.e. $\frac{\delta S}{\delta a}$, by $E_a$.

Then $S$ is gauge invariant when

$$\delta S = \delta a E_a + \delta b E_b +\delta c E_c = 0 \tag{1}$$

This gives

$$\delta c = - (\delta a E_a + \delta b E_b)/E_c   \tag{2}$$

From the above equation $\delta c$ can be obtained for arbitrary $\delta a$ and $\delta b$. It is not necessary to have a relation b/w $\,\delta a$ and $\delta b$. This implies that there is an infinite number of gauge-transformations here. At first I was very puzzled by this property of infinite number of gauge transformations. But then a kind PSE responder directed me to look into "*trivial gauge transformations*" in Ref. 1.

I looked there and I deduced that the gauge transformation discussed in (1) and (2) above is a trivial gauge transformation. I even showed in an [answer](https://physics.stackexchange.com/a/757631/363071) to my earlier question how the above gauge transformation can be expressed with an antisymmetric matrix as stated by Theorem 3.1 in Ref. 1.

But I think I made a mistake in my earlier post where I said that $\delta c$ vanishes on-shell. When the equations of motion hold, i.e. when $E_a=E_b=E_c=0$, $\delta c$ in (2) becomes undefined; it does not vanish. Does that mean that (2) is not a trivial gauge transformation? If so, how can one explain the infinite number of gauge transformations in (2)?

Equations (1) and (2) hold true for **all gauge transformations**. If (2) is indeed a trivial gauge transformation then doesn't that imply that all gauge transformations are trivial? But every gauge transformation cannot be trivial. How to distinguish a trivial gauge transformation from a non-trivial one?

References:

[1](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/757423/363071): M. Henneaux & C. Teitelboim, Quantization of Gauge Systems, 1994; subsection 3.1.5.

Comment: I am not sure that I can give a precise answer, but classes of admissible gauge transformations do matter. There is a related discussion here
https://arxiv.org/abs/hep-th/9304057
Essentially, it says that if we allow any types of non-localities, any action is gauge invariant with respect to some non-local gauge transformation. Most dangerous are precisely transformations in which you allow to divide by equations of motion.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Whether or not eq. (2) becomes undefined at the locus of solutions to the equations of motion depends on the specific functional forms of $\delta a$ and $\delta b$. Arguably we should only admit those tuples $(\delta a, \delta b, \delta c)$ as defining a transformation at all for which none of the three $\delta x^i$ are singular anywhere.

Of those that are non-singular anywhere, it can happen that the $\delta x^i$ are zero on-shell or it can happen that they aren't - eq. (2) doesn't say anything about that since the non-singular ones will have to "cancel" the $E_i$ terms in some way. When they're zero on-shell they're trivial gauge transformations, when they're not they aren't.

Comment: Thanks! So I gather you're saying that a transformation which is not well-defined (is either undefined or singular) on-shell, should not be considered a gauge transformation. But even if a transformation is undefined on-shell, it can keep the action and its equations of motion invariant. So what justification can we give to not identify such a transformation as a gauge transformation?

Comment: @Baela I argue it's not "a transformation" if it is singular somewhere. A transformation by definition is a map on the entire phase space; something that's singular at some point is not such a map. Doesn't really matter if the singularity is on-shell or not.

Comment: That explains everything and clears all my confusion now. Thanks!